# Copy account name from URL to clipboard

Tags: javascript

I'll apologize in advance for being a newb, I'm pretty new to the world of programming so show some mercy XD

I'm trying to make a script that will copy only the account name from the top browser URL but I've hit a brick wall on this part.

```html
const regex = /account\/(.*)\/#photos/gm;
const str = `https://internal.DUMMYSITE.com/compliance/account/ACCOUNTNAME/#photos`;
let m = regex.exec(str);

var dummy = document.createElement(m),
    text = window.location.href;

document.body.appendChild(dummy);
dummy.value = text;
dummy.select();
document.execCommand('copy');
document.body.removeChild(dummy);
```

So it works fine for the most part, in my actual code I've used a random URL that follows the format and the "ACCOUNTNAME" part is actually a real account name. Every time I run the code it copies the text that I've added on the account name.

What am I doing wrong?

I'll thank everyone in advance, cheers!

Comment: Are you asking how to just get the ACCOUNTNAME text? If so its in `m[1]`.  Note you pass `m` to `createElement()` but that won't work as neither `m` nor `m[1]` is a valid element name.

Comment: Yes I'm asking exactly that, I only need the text, I simply add [1] to createElement? or did I understand that incorrectly?

Comment: I would use an existing solution, E.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33928558/246342

Comment: Thanks for providing the post but which code exactly, like I said I'm a newb and I would very much appreciate it if you could paste the one here xD

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lacytqfm/1/

Comment: Aight so it would appear that I have the same problem, I added all the code but it copies the same account name that is present in the URL.

To give you some context. 

I'm supposed to review accounts, I copy the account name from the URL in chrome and paste it to my system.

The URL will change very often so I need a script that will copy the account name.

Hope we can find a solution, cheers!

Comment: I must also add that I'm using AutoControl and I've added a shortcut hotkey to the code, so per se, I'll be pressing CTRL+E to instantly copy the accountname